# Terraform: Create A Records for all FQDN from Cosmos DB Private Endpoint

Tags: terraform, devops, azure-rm

I am working on setting up private networking on Cosmos DB. I have following code to create Private Endpoint and A Record, based on bool 'private_networking_enabled' :

```
module "cosmos_db" {
  source = "../shared/cosmos/db"

}

module "cosmos_db_endpoint" {
  source = "../shared/network/private_endpoint"

  count = local.cosmos_account_network_config.private_networking_enabled ? 1 : 0

  depends_on = [
    module.cosmos_db,
    data.azurerm_subnet.bkend,
  ]

  env_config = local.env_config

  config = {
    connected_resource      = module.cosmos_db.db_config.account_id
    endpoint_name           = "${module.cosmos_db.db_config.account_name}-pep"
    service_connection_name = "${module.cosmos_db.db_config.account_name}-sc"
    subnet_id               = data.azurerm_subnet.bkend.id
    subresource_names       = ["Sql"]
  }
}

module "cosmos_db_private_network_a_record" {
  source = "../shared/private_dns/private_dns_a_record"

  for_each = merge(
    local.cosmos_account_network_config.private_networking_enabled ?
    { for config in module.cosmos_db_endpoint[0].config.custom_dns_configs : config.fqdn => config.ip_addresses } :
    {}
  )

  depends_on = [
    module.cosmos_db,
    module.cosmos_db_endpoint
  ]

  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.hubdns
  }

  env_config = local.env_config

  config = {
    a_record_name         = split(".", each.key)[0]
    private_dns_zone_name = "privatelink.documents.azure.com"
    private_ip_address    = each.value
    ttl                   = 3600
  }
}
```

My pipeline is failing with follwoing error:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on ..\modules\ps2\database.tf line 58, in module "cosmos_db_private_network_a_record":
│   58:   for_each = merge(
│   59:     local.cosmos_account_network_config.private_networking_enabled ?
│   60:     { for config in module.cosmos_db_endpoint[0].config.custom_dns_configs : config.fqdn => config.ip_addresses } :
│   61:     {}
│   62:   )
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.cosmos_account_network_config.private_networking_enabled is true
│     │ module.cosmos_db_endpoint[0].config.custom_dns_configs is a list of object, known only after apply
```

I also tried creating a map localy, but it did not help

```
locals {
  custom_dns_map = {
    for config in module.cosmos_db_endpoint[0].config.custom_dns_configs :
    config.fqdn => config.ip_addresses
  }
}

module "cosmos_db_private_network_a_record" {
  source = "../shared/private_dns/private_dns_a_record"

  for_each = local.cosmos_account_network_config.private_networking_enabled ? module.cosmos_db_endpoint[0].config.custom_dns_configs : [0]

  depends_on = [
    module.cosmos_db,
    module.cosmos_db_endpoint
  ]

  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.hubdns
  }

  env_config = local.env_config

  config = {
    a_record_name         = split(".", each.key)[0]
    private_dns_zone_name = "privatelink.documents.azure.com"
    private_ip_address    = element(each.value, 0)
    ttl                   = 3600
  }
}
```

Could you please help point out what I am missing here?

What I am looking for is to create a Private endpoint for default and region-specific FQDN for the cosmos db

```
xxxxx.dcouments.azure.com
xxxxx-eastus.documents.azure.com
xxxxx-westus.documents.azure.com
```

Comment: What I am looking for is to create Private endpoint for default and region-specific FQDN for cosmos

Comment: The error is clear "list of object, known only after apply". Your `for_each` can't depend on a runtime event. All must be known at plan time. You have to re-architect your infrastructure, so that everything is known before you apply it.

Comment: This error is coming at Terraform Plan stage

Comment: Yes, because number of iterations is not known at plan.

Comment: @Marcin - Could you please help me with Code Snippet?